# Cloud storage client libraries not working. No module appengine.api

Tags: google-app-engine, pydev

I'm trying to set up the cloud storage client libraries so I can store images for my gae app using python.  I'm following the instructions here:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries

Unfortunately when I import the storage module:

from google.cloud import storage

something goes wrong saying:

ImportError: No module named appengine.api

Is there a way i can check if I have appengine.api installed at all (which I believe i do.  It should have been included in the app engine sdk i installed)?  If it's not installed how can I install it?

Answer (score 3):

The GCS library is **not** included the GAE SDK, it has to be [vendored in as a 3rd party lib](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library).

See also [Downloading the client library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage#downloading_the_client_library) in the GAE [Setting Up Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage) doc.

Comment: Hi i have downloaded and added this into the lib folder still getting the same error, any ideas?

Comment: Can you ask it as a separate question describing your case? Your comment to the other post suggests you use flex env, this post is about standard env.